# Error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67 in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, smtp, laravel-5, token, email-verification

Actually,I want to redirect my user to the email verification page after signup process and asking him/her to enter the verification code sent to his/her email. I will be glad if you tell me the process or recommend me any tutorial.

I have already made my working authentication system . I have searched a lot on internet but all i can find is the requirement of laravel auth which i am not using.

On signing up I am getting the above mentioned error.

If you need to see my code , just tell me. I'll post it.

This question is in reference to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38066753/how-to-build-an-email-verification-system-using-laravel-5-2-with-custom-controll/38101210?noredirect=1#comment63640254_38101210

Comment: Would you share your routes file? (Pastebin)

Comment: routes.php : http://laravel.io/bin/Oe3PX

Comment: It looks weird that the 'web' middleware group is not affecting your controller's method... It shouldnt be checking the token.

Comment: Is that route outside any groups? Im on small screen and can check correctly because of indentation

Comment: sorry,didnt get you!

Comment: I see that the route group with the middleware "web" is commented out (line 16). The thing is that you should not have this problem if this middleware is disabled for your validation entry.

Comment: from line 43 i removed web from auth:web now error is : stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Comment: Something really weird going on here. Can you post your http kernel file?

Comment: kernel.php http://laravel.io/bin/d9o8D

Comment: is that error right after you click the link of your mail? Is it a local environment or online testing env? Would you in that case post the full url you receive on the email body?

Comment: error is right after clicking signup button and its a local environment.

Comment: Ok, then your routes file is wrong

Comment: ohk....then what changes would you suggest?

Comment: Its complex to debug on this context. Try with these routes http://laravel.io/bin/KkxEK . You still owe me the complete path of the link you receive by email

Comment: {{ URL::to('register/verify/' . $confirmation_code) }}  this would be the link received by email

Comment: That is the code that generates the actual link. When you open the email, what is the actual link that you click?

Comment: What results did you get with the routes y provided you?

Comment: Getting  the same error :(

Comment: AuthController.php http://laravel.io/bin/Dez2o

Comment: RegistrationController.php http://laravel.io/bin/PXO4o

Comment: email.blade.php http://laravel.io/bin/42YqL

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. **Here is the best tutorial i came across when i built laravel 5.2 registration.**

https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/2015/06/15/how-to-make-user-login-and-registration-laravel-5-1/